# Drawing a background grid based on \linespread value

Tags: xetex, line-spacing, grids

I’m trying to help a friend set an Arabic book in LaTeX and I’m facing [this very same uneven line spacing issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126075/729) (except that the book is completely in Arabic).

Now I’m trying to find the `\linespread` setting that is just big enough to ensure even line spacing but not any bigger, so I thought drawing a grid and visually examining the lines with different setting to find the desired ones.

But, I do not even understand what, say, `1.5` in `\linespread{1.5}` actually mean (I read many discussions and answers but I still don’t get it), so I need help in:

- Setting a background grid (horizontal lines are enough).
- Make the spacing between grid lines follow `\linespread` setting i.e. they should represent the ideal line spacing if TeX didn’t do its vertical glue magic.

(I tried `grid` option of `eso-pic` but couldn’t wrap my head around the meaning of its options to get what I described above).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do what you want. A box consisting of the requested number of lines, drawn at the baselines, is added with `\AtBeginShipout`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi,picture,xcolor}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    \color{red}%
    \put(\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin,
         -\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\topskip)%
      {%
       \vtop to\dimexpr\vsize+\baselineskip{
         \hrule
         \leaders\vbox to\baselineskip{\hrule width\hsize\vfill}\vfill
       }%
      }%
  }%
}

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant
\end{document}
```

[image]

What does `\linespread{1.5}` do? Every time LaTeX does a setting of `\baselineskip`, it will multiply the normal value by that factor. For instance, if the normal baselineskip is 12pt, it will become 18pt; for `\small`, when the normal value is 11pt, it will become 16.5pt. However, `\topskip` is not modified.

Comment: Thanks, it does not seems not to play nice with `bidi` when the document is set to RTL (i.e. `\usepackage[rldocument]{bidi}`) generating some warnings and the grid is displaced, but I can live with that.

Comment: @egreg It's a helpful post, would you please help hint me how to put 3 line grid for each text line? one on top, one on middle and another one on bottom.

Comment: @lucky1928 That's quite an addition. Please, ask a follow-up question.

Answer (score 3):

With package `bidi-atbegshi`, this even becomes much easier (you only have to change `\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft` in @egreg's code to `\AtBeginShipoutUpperRight`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bidi-atbegshi,picture,xcolor}
\usepackage[RTLdocument]{bidi}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperRight{%
    {\color{red}%
    \put(\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin,
         -\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\topskip)%
      {%
       \vtop to\dimexpr\vsize+\baselineskip{
         \hrule
         \leaders\vbox to\baselineskip{\hrule width\hsize\vfill}\vfill
       }%
      }%
  }%
 }%
}

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little change to @egreg's code, this works fine in RTL too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi,picture,xcolor}
\usepackage[RTLdocument]{bidi}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    {\color{red}%
    \put(\dimexpr -1in-\oddsidemargin,
         -\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\topskip)%
      {%
       \vtop to\dimexpr\vsize+\baselineskip{
         \hrule
         \leaders\vbox to\baselineskip{\hrule width\hsize\vfill}\vfill
       }%
      }%
  }}%
}

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant
\end{document}
```

and here is what you get:

[image]