# show baseline in two columns

Tags: line-spacing, grids

This is a follow-up to [Drawing a background grid based on linespread value](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150619).  In a two-column document, the background lines are drawn in the first column only.  Is there a way to show them in both columns?

Here is a short document for testing:

```
% compile with lualatex or xelatex:
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,lipsum,microtype}
\setmainfont[Contextuals=Alternate]{EB Garamond}
\linespread{1.0609}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parindent}{1em}}
\setlength{\topskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage[centering,columnsep=1.5em,heightrounded]{geometry}
% grid from tex.stackexchange.com/a/150621:
\usepackage{atbegshi,picture,xcolor}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    \color{red}%
    \put(\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin,
    -\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\topskip)%
    {%
      \vtop to\dimexpr\vsize+\baselineskip{
        \hrule
        \leaders\vbox to\baselineskip{\hrule width\hsize\vfill}\vfill
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\raggedbottom
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a *hack* that seems to work:

[image]

### Notes:

- The *hack* is the magic number `4.1in` that was guessed at. This should really be computed based on the column widths and the column separation.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\linespread{1.0609}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parindent}{1em}}
\setlength{\topskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage[centering,columnsep=1.5em,heightrounded]{geometry}
% grid from tex.stackexchange.com/a/150621:
\usepackage{atbegshi,picture,xcolor}
\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    \color{red}%
    \put(\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin,
    -\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\topskip)%
    {%
      \vtop to\dimexpr\vsize+\baselineskip{
        \hrule
        \leaders\vbox to\baselineskip{\hrule width\hsize\vfill}\vfill
      }%
    }%
    \color{blue}%
    \put(\dimexpr 4.1in+\oddsidemargin,
    -\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\topskip)%
    {%
      \vtop to\dimexpr\vsize+\baselineskip{
        \hrule
        \leaders\vbox to\baselineskip{\hrule width\hsize\vfill}\vfill
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\raggedbottom
\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I’ll wait a little while before accepting this, in case another interesting solution appears, but this one does seem to do the trick.

Comment: @Thérèse: No problem. Like, I said it was just a hack and seemed to work. Am hoping a more detailed (and flexible) answer will show up so I can delete this one.