# Odd behavior after minipage environment

Tags: minipage

I have this code where, for demonstrative purposes, I have drawn in red lines at integer values of `\baselineskip` and framed the minipages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[margin = 1.0in, showframe, heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}% Remove space between fbox frame and content

% Red lines at baselines.
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{atbegshi,picture,xcolor}
\AtBeginShipout{%
    \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
        \color{red}%
         \put(\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin,
             -\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\topskip)%
        {%
            \vtop to\dimexpr\vsize+\baselineskip{
            \hrule
            \leaders\vbox to\baselineskip{\hrule width\hsize\vfill}\vfill
        }%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}

    \fbox
    {%
        \begin{minipage}[t][\heightof{Lorem} + 9\baselineskip]{0.85\textwidth}
            \lipsum[1]
        \end{minipage}%
    }

    \hfill

    Hello,

\end{document}
```

My question is simple: why isn't the baseline of "Hello," at precisely the next red line after the minipage?

[image: output]

Comment: one more close brace is needed to match the opener for `\vtop` in the definition of `\AtBeginShipout`.  i can't figure out why the `\hfill` should be needed, but removing it only makes things worse, and `\strut`s don't help either.

Comment: If I ditch the specific height of the minipage, use `\lipsum*[1]\strut` and add a `\par` before `Hello` it seems to match. Some of the box wizards my explain the actual size of the boxes

Comment: Nice trick with the red lines by the way

Comment: use `[b]` not `[t]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Then you move the problem from the bottom to the top. ;-)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek but the example only had text below, and top of the page is easier to control:-)  latex3 coffins are designed for this problem (can have two or more reference points) (but +1 for your answer anyway:-)

Comment: @daleif Credit for the red lines goes to egreg http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150619/drawing-a-background-grid-based-on-linespread-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following

```
\begin{minipage}[t][\heightof{Lorem} + 9\baselineskip]{0.85\textwidth}
```

assigns the `minipage` the height of the first line ("Lorem"). Thus the `\topskip` setting is correct with regarding to the grid lines.

However the depth of the box is the remaining space of `9\baselineskip`. The depth of the last line sticks even outside the box. Because of the very large depth of the `minipage`, `\baselineskip` is not used and set, but `\lineskip` (default: 1 pt). The depth of the "g" is sticking out of the box and is around 2 pt, the next line "Hello" overprints the descender of the "g" (without the `\hfill` of course).

The example can be fixed in two ways:

- Setting `\prevdepth` to zero:

  ```
  \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][\heightof{Lorem} + 9\baselineskip]{0.85\textwidth}
      \lipsum[1]
    \end{minipage}%
  }\par
  \setlength{\prevdepth}{0pt}
  Hello,
  ```

  An overlarge descender of the last line of the `minipage` or accented uppercase letters might clash then, because TeX does not know about the depth of the last line, when setting the "Hello" line. But the grid is more respected.
- A box can be added, which simulates the depth of the last line in the `minipage`:

  ```
  \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][\heightof{Lorem} + 9\baselineskip]{0.85\textwidth}
      \lipsum[1]
      \par
      \xdef\lastprevdepth{\the\prevdepth}%
    \end{minipage}%
  }\par
  \nobreak
  \nointerlineskip 
  \hbox{\vrule width0pt depth\lastprevdepth}
  Hello,
  ```

Result in both cases:

> [image: Result]