# Setting `\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen` for a single paragraph then resetting to default without breaking lines

Tags: line-spacing, inline

I am trying to use `\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen` for the same reasons as questions [522530](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/522530/104780) and [49072](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49072/104780) namely I have uneven spacing between lines when including mathematical notation (specifically subscripts/superscripts).

In my case, I want to apply the `lineskiplimit` tweak **for a single paragraph**. Unfortunately:

1. When I enclose the whole paragraph in curly brackets `{...}` together with the tweak, I don't see any change;
2. If I don't enclose, then the uneven spacing vanishes but the effect persists until I break a line - which is problematic because, if I have an `align` environment after the paragraph I want to reduce line spacing, then by breaking the line I get a large gap between the end of the paragraph and my equation.

**Is there a way to set then reset the `\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen`tweak?** I have tried creating a new command and environment to do it, but I don't see any impact.

Comment: put the blank line ending the paragraph before the `}`

Comment: but if it's just one para you could instead do `\smash{$X^2$}` ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\smash{}` does the trick!